# ag-grid: Async function inside valuegetter to calculate cell value which depends on other column(s)

Tags: asynchronous, ag-grid, calculated-columns, ag-grid-angular

In my application, a calculated column depends on other column for calculation, but the calculation needs to be done on the server. Trying to figure out a way to do that using valueGetter to call the REST service and update that value for the column on success.

```
const columnDefs = [
  { headerName: 'Make', field: 'make' },
  { headerName: 'Tax', field: 'tax', editable: true },
  {
    headerName: 'Price',
    field: 'price',
    valueGetter: (params) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        params.data.price = params.data.tax + 1;
        params.api.refreshCells({
          rowNodes: [params.node],
          columns: [params.column],
        });
        console.log('cell refreshed');
      }, 1000);
      params.data.price = '';
      return -9999;
    },
  },
];
```

**But this causes the valueGetter to be called over and over as the cell is updated and the grid needs the updated value.** Is there any other way of acheiving this or if I can use some other method to update the column value which will not trigger change detection?

Here's link for what I'm trying to do: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-typescript-async-value-getter?file=src/main.ts